# react-native-twilio-video-webrtc Could not set unknown property 'namespace' error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, twilio

I am running my React Native template that contains react-native-twilio-webrtc on Android and am getting namespace and compileSdkVersion is not specified error. I need help to resolve this error. Below is the error message:

> 1: Task failed with an exception.

---

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Benjamin_Ikwuagwu\Downloads\releases_react-native-video-chat-app\videoChat\ReactNativeVideoChat\node_modules\react-native-twilio-video-webrtc\android\build.gradle' line: 10
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'.

> Could not set unknown property 'namespace' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

This is my android/build.gradle

```js
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Benjamin_Ikwuagwu\Downloads\releases_react-native-video-chat-app\videoChat\ReactNativeVideoChat\node_modules\react-native-twilio-video-webrtc\android\build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'.
> Could not set unknown property 'namespace' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

Comment: Just an FYI, Twilio Programmable Video is no longer supported, and will end of life on December 5th, 2024. The [official migration path](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/programmable-video-eol-notice) is to migrate to [Zoom Video SDK](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/twilio/). We are happy to support your use case and we have an official [React Native Video SDK](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/react-native/).